# Google Cloud SQL Postgres 9.6 enabling parallel query execution

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm testing some work on a Google Cloud SQL instance of Postgres 9.6 and want to see how enabling parallel queries will improve (or not) the performance.  I have followed the process here:

https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql96-parallel-sequential-scan/

But the explain plan doesn't indicate that its using worker nodes.  To validate that I did it correctly I installed Postgres on my local machine and made the changes and it all worked and the explain plan showed workers being used.

Does anyone know of specific reasons or extra steps needed in Google Cloud SQL to get this working.

Thanks

Matt

**[EDIT]**

The steps I took to change the setting on GCP were:

- from the DB Overview page (the one with the CPU Utilisation graph)
- Click on Connect using Cloud Shell (underneath the connect to this instance box)
- execute this command sudo nano /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf
- remove the # from max_parallel_workers_per_gather and max_worker_processes
- change max_parallel_workers_per_gather to 8 (only 4 cores so I believe that 3 is the max to show benefits, but I don't believe any harm is done using 8)
- ctrl-x then y
- click the restart button on the DB overview page

Having repeated those steps this morning, I see the changes are now undone in the config file. I'm guessing this is due to the method i'm using to connect to the DB, ie using cloud shell...

And just noticed that using SET max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 8; works and I get the workers being used in the explain plan. So my question then is how do I change it in config for ALL sessions as opposed to on a per session basis.

Comment: What does `show max_parallel_workers_per_gather;` give you?

Comment: Ah, there we go, still shows 0!  I'll post my steps to change the config file in Google as clearly they worked locally, but not on GCP.  (I didn't know about the show command... cheers)

Comment: After the edit above, the question is now, how do I change it in config for ALL sessions as opposed to on a per session basis?

Comment: `alter user set ...` or `alter system set ...`